# Chrome Version 75.0.3770.80 (Official Build) (64-bit) - unable to begin transaction (3850 disk I/O error)

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome, web-sql

In windows 7 chrome latestVersion 75.0.3770.80 (Official Build) (64-bit)
got an error while get data and write data to chrome browser db in web sql.
"unable to begin transaction (3850 disk I/O error)". Do you know any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 3):

This issue happens if you edit (insert/replace/update) the same data to the same table at the same time. One of the possible cases is you're having 2 tabs opened that access the same database. This is chrome regression since it was working before v75. Possible solutions are:

- You could either wait until it gets fixed in chrome.
- You could implement a manual lock mechanism, to edit data only on the main tab.